# how to pass Xml data to C#.net textbox

Tags: c#, xml

I tried many times. I couldn't get the right answer. this the API I used to make the System I attached the screenshot below

this API Url - country what I typed here in London all relevant data has to displayed below the XML file about the weather information of the country what I Entered please look that the screenshot below

[image]

This is the C# form screenshot I attached below

[image]

When you Enter the city name in the text box the relevant city whether information has to display on below of the textboxes such as (Temperature, Humidity)

so far I tried the code is this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string weburl = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.xml?key=02d3de968c424e20b5a74149172409   &q=" + textBox1.Text + "&mode=xml";

        }
```

textbox1 mean city

when I enter the city name result has to be displayed below the textboxes

I hope all understand my problem please give me the Answer soon

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code (or in this case xml), instead provide it in text form

Comment: have a look at [WebClient (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, there are also many tutorials for this

Comment: where is the code to get the web request response? You got the URL right, but next step is to fire an http web request to get the response as xml. After which you need to parse the xml using `XMLDocument` or any other libraries known and get the specific elements from xml. The question you have posted is asking for complete code on reading response of a web request and parsing xml content. Please try some code and let us know if you are stuck.

Comment: can you write the code it is more helpful for me.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is *not* a free coding service. Do your homework, and please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Furthermore, do not post code (including file contents) as image. Instead, post it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deleted your previous posting before I could respond.  Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string city = "London";
            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.xml?key=02d3de968c424e20b5a74149172409&q={0}&mode=xml", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);

            string temp = (string)doc.Descendants("temp_c").FirstOrDefault();
            string humidity = (string)doc.Descendants("humidity").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: temp_c,humidity display on the textbox fields below

Comment: simply textbox1.Text = temp; textbox2.Text = humidity;

Comment: thanks, sir working well. how to add the weather forecast

Comment: sir whether forecast for coming up weeks just 7 days result

Comment: add the grid of c# and how to display

Comment: Forecast is a different uri .  Change "current" to "forecast".

Comment: Where are you getting picture box?

Comment: <icon>//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png</icon>    this is the picture i want diplay on the picture box in c#

Comment: Should make new posting.  This one is for xml.  You want to copy a picture from a url to a picturebox.